# AWS Systems manager - how to manage access to parameters under the root path?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm going to organize parameters across different departments in a hierarchical fashion similar to the below example:

```
/Finance/Accountants/UserList
/Finance/Analysts/UserList
/HR/Employees/EU/UserList
```

Then I want to manage access to parameters with IAM policies. According to the below excerpt from the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-su-organize.html), if there is a **User A** that has permissions to access `/Finance/Accountants` he can also access `/Finance/Analysts` by calling `GetParametersByPath` recursively.

And here is a question: What if a **User A** tries to access Parameter store by the root path: "/" recursively. In this case will he be able to access parameters under the `/HR` path as well even if he is explicitly denied to do so?

> If a user has access to a path, then the user can access all levels of
>   that path. For example, if a user has permission to access path /a,
>   then the user can also access /a/b. Even if a user has explicitly been
>   denied access in IAM for parameter /b, they can still call the
>   GetParametersByPath API action recursively and view /a/b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its only for **sub-levels**, not **parent levels**.

If access is for `/Finance/Accountants*` (not `/*` or `/Finance*`), user can't query `GetParametersByPath` for `/Finance` and get all its sub-levels.

You can **Deny `GetParametersByPath` Action**, to make it more explicit. Allow / Deny it only for specific paths or only if `recursive=True` passed in request.

You can also use [tag based IAM policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-access.html#sysman-paramstore-access-tag), this will require tagging parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. Is it possible to allow the user to query `/*` but to get only the parameters from a number of allowed paths. For example: `/Finance/Accountants*`, `/HR/Employees`.